# Loss of ios swift application text after publishing to app store following internationalization

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, internationalization, nslocalizedstring

first post and lone spare time programmer here. In short i internationalised my app by adding translations for french and Spanish and it tested without issue on simulator and Iphone 6 (version 12.4.6), there are no errors or app crashes.

When i published the app, it was approved. When i updated the app on my other phone from the app store update, it lost all NSLocalized text (so seems like link broken) and the text field with placeholder now has a black background. This makes the app unusable. I hastily rolled back the version to one pre-localisation however it seems to have inherited the same issue however it doesn't make sense as most of the strings are hardcoded (not NSlocalized). The phone that its working on still works on the rollback. The phones it's not working on are still not working with the same issue.

I didn't think there was any code that would help. Generally after feedback in case this has happened to others or for suggestions to fix.

Thinking I made a mistake, I tested on another iphone 6s, version 13.4 and it was still working correctly much to my confusion. Asking someone else to check it on their Iphone XS version 13.4 and it was also not working with the same issue.

To localise, I added localisation to the fixed text in the app which created the main.strings files for the languages which I filled out. 
I also added the Localizable strings file and then completed them. This highlighted that I hadn’t setup the app to have international strings so went through and redid the hardcoded and programmatic text to come from the internationalized strings file.

Its like the update 1.2 corrupted the app so not sure how to resolve. 
It also seems like the text lookups using “NSLocalizedString("text.", comment: "this is comment")are not finding the text for some reason. I don’t understand how it works perfect on testing but not when deployed.

What I’ve done to try and resolve:
Thinking the issue was phone based since it works on another identical phone, I tried closing the app, rebooting the phone, uninstalling and reinstalling the app but to no avail. I tried this on other phones also.

Software configuration:
 XCODE: Version 11.3.1 (11C504)
Macbook: Macbook air 13": 10.14.5 
Test Phone: Iphone 6, version 12.4.6, MG4F2X/A
Other Phone app update works on- Iphone 6s, Version 13.4, model MN0W2X/A 
Phones app not working on:
Iphone 6s, Version 13.4, model MN0W2X/A and Iphone XS, Version 13.4

Thankyou in advance.

[Screenshot of app with text working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqkDd.png)

[Screenshot of app with loss of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt7cE.png)

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was a bit of a n00b issue. What confused me was that it worked on some phones but not others which made no sense and some text remained and others didn't.

Dark Mode was the answer.
Thus, the lazy fix was to change all text to black which solved my problem and was even able to verify on phones and simulator. Yay!

Ultimately you can opt-out of Dark Mode(programmatically or adding a key to info.plist) though it's not recommended as its better to improve an apps functionality by embracing the themes available. There's plenty of available material online on how to do this so won't copy it all here, just the simple plist method.

Info.plist method - add key UIUserInterfaceStyle in your app info.plist and set its value to Light or Dark. This will override the app default style to the value you provide.

Context & explanation below.
Apparently: "Dark Mode was introduced in iOS 13 and announced at WWDC 2019. It adds a darker theme to iOS and allows you to do the same for your app". I was aware of Dark Mode and have it enabled on my phone (and forgotten about) but didn't realise you had to change the app to suit this (being a spare time programmer). One  big hint should have been the text fields were black or that all non standard coloured text remained.

I don't recall changing the app background away from the default to white but I must have. That coupled with the font colour being default and thus when Dark Mode was enabled, all text was changed to white. Like I said, n00b. Lets add that to the standard tests I always need to complete.

Thanks for listening.

## Darkmode